# Have rotation for the object the same as the face

Tags: axis

Hello so I have the following problem. I created a door as a seperate object. I combined this then with another on. I got it to the point where I want it but now I want it rotated a way. That it is on the same rotation as the the face.

Currently I have it like this but as you can see it sticks out. How can I achive this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Think I figured it out. Select the object > snap to face> same orientation (option or something) then place it. This worked for me I could then place it on the right spot :D

Comment: oh ok I misunderstood your problem  ;)

Comment: Still thank you for your response :)